# Unable to get Tomcat Home Page

Tags: tomcat, cmd, catalina

I enter the following URL `http://localhost:8081` in my browser and end up with a connection error. After starting tomcat using the catalina script, I get a blank page. Any one have any idea why it so?

Comment: do you want kinda give us a hint as to what you mean? please give us details of what you have changed from the default configuration, what version of tomcat and what you are trying to achieve...we aren't mind readers

Comment: Pah, speak for yourself, @gid. Right now, you're thinking of.... a baloney sandwich.  Right?

Comment: I didnt change any configuration. i was able to get the tomcat before a week. I dont know hat happened now

Comment: I am using tomcat5.0.30. I need to get the Tomcat home page

Comment: I am sorry if I didnt give necessary information. Sorry for the trouble

Comment: Tomcat starts http at  http://localhost:8080 not  http://localhost:8081

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat starts http at  localhost:8080 .
Check the server configuration by going to java build path.